# tomcat - caching issue on class files

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, caching

I am developing a plain java web application(JSPs/Servlets) using Netbeans 7.4 on Apache Tomcat 7.0. I have problems on my production server (windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise) whereas it works perfect on my localhost. I suspect it to be cache issue.

The problem is that I am deploying a new version of my application to my production server, but it serves the old application. At first I thought it is a cache problem, but after cleaning work and app directory and restarting tomcat (tried all combinations...), nothing seems to be changed.

My server directory structure is like below:

- Tomcat 7.0

  - webapps
  - myapp

    - ROOT
    - ROOT.war
    - images
  - otherapp
  - work
  - conf
  - etc.

JSP files are changed or created as expected but the class files persist to behave like before.

Did you have any similar problem? Since I had no similar ones before I am stuck about the possibilities? If you can give me some pointers, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Did you restarted the context?

Comment: sorry, I do not get what you mean by context, I just restart the server after cleaning and deploying. If that is what you mean, yes I restart all the time :)

Comment: remove the work folder and clean up the temporary files and try again,

Comment: I had already done it, tried it again, still no good! I suspect it is something else. Although I am cleaning the browser cache every time, I will use another network for viewing and deploying.

Comment: I found the reason for not renewing the classes. The codebase which I was working had classes folder in WEB_INF, already compiled. This prevents netbeans to override the WEB-INF with newly compiled classes. This is a silly mistake, please excuse me, anyway thanks for your attention. Keep in mind that classes are always in WEB-INF while JSPs may be in work/Catalina/. and keep your WEB-INF clean :)